# Weird Indefinite Integral Question

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm solving a question regarding indefinite integrals.

If $$\int_2^x f(t) \,dt= \frac{(6x)}{\sqrt{(9x^2-20)}} - 3$$ then 
$$\int_2^\infty f(t) \,dt$$
is

I thought I would replace the infinity with a variable such as b and set a limit going to infinity. Then I would take the antiderivative of the expression in the first integral and evaluate it that way. If I do that I am getting the expression to be divergent. Is this correct?

Comment: Cool. All I wanted. Do you take the antiderivative of the expression though?

Comment: Oops, read wrong. Will address in an answer!

Comment: Alright. I felt something was fishy with my method.

Comment: Hint: $\;\cfrac{x}{\sqrt{9x^2-20}}=\cfrac{1}{\sqrt{9-\frac{20}{x^2}}}\;$ for $\;x \gt 0\,$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the integration step has already been done for you! There is some function $F(x)$ defined as $$F(x) = \int_2^x f(t)~\mathrm{d}t =  \frac{6x}{\sqrt{9 x^2 -20}} -3.$$

As such, we look at 
$$\int_2^\infty f(t) ~\mathrm{d}t = \lim_{x \to \infty} \int_2^{x}f(t) ~\mathrm{d}t = \lim_{x \to \infty} F(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{6x}{\sqrt{9 x^2 -20}} -3. $$

Comment: Ah. That is the trick in the question. I should have recognized this. Thank you and I will verify this answer when allowed

Comment: Same, apologies for my first comment (was skimming too quickly).

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int_2^\infty f(t)\,dt = \lim_{x\to\infty} \int_2^x f(t) \,dt= \lim_{x\to\infty} \left( \frac{6x}{\sqrt{9x^2-20}} - 3 \right)
$$
$$
\left( = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac 6 {\sqrt{9 - \dfrac{20}{x^2}}} = \text{etc.} \right)
$$